# Arrange most recently dragged images to the top

Tags: php, jquery, html, draggable

I've managed to create a page on which three draggable images contained inside separate divs appear randomly from a directory and at random positions.

The problem is one image will always obscure another when dragged. Is it possible to make it so that upon using the dragging interaction, that image is 'rearranged' to the top so that the user is in control of the order of arrangement?

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<body>
    <center>
<!-- image displays here -->

    <img src="_" class="draggable ui-draggable" />

<img src="_" class="draggable ui-draggable" /></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('.draggable').draggable({ scroll: true, cursor: "move"});

});

$('img').hide().one("load",function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(2000);
}).each(function(){
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
});


</script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a PHP question.  Can you provide just the rendered HTML and Javascript?

Comment: Set the z-index of the last dragged item to a higher number than the other draggables. You can use addClass and removeClass to accomplish this. Only works on positioned elements.

Comment: You should take a look at [the JQueryUI documentation](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).  I think you're looking for [snapTolerance](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snapTolerance) or [snapMode](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snapMode)

Comment: @mtr.web  Actually, it seems like the [stack](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack) option would be the one

Comment: Thanks so much, I think the stack option is what I'm looking for however I'm struggling to see where to place it as it then interferees with the drag interaction. Where in relation to the drag function to I place this?

Comment: @AlfredCassels  Please update your question to show what you tried.  Also, it would be good if you removed the PHP code and showed the _rendered_ HTML instead, as I had asked originally.

Comment: @PatrickQ By update do you mean edit? What is rendered html?

I've used the stack

```  $(function () {
        $(".drag").draggable({            
            stack: ".drag"
        });
    });```  

Can the drag classed be used on images as well as divs?

Comment: @AlfredCassels  The rendered HTML is the HTML created by the PHP.  It's what is actually used in your browser.